# Flutter Driver fails on dev server (Unable to connect to Chrome debug port: 37475)

Tags: flutter, testing, flutter-web, webdeploy, flutterdriver

I developed an app, wrote some tests, tests are successful locally. When I try running tests on my dev server they fail. I think the problem is with an absence of monitor on the server. How would I run tests in headless mode or solve this problem in any other way? Here are the [logs](https://pastebin.com/7BbJByfn) after running verbose

```
flutter run -d chrome --verbose
```

```
flutter drive --release --driver-port=4444 --target=test_driver/app.dart -d chrome
```

this throws an [exception](https://pastebin.com/jvRnN5bE). I have chromedriver running on port 4444 btw